# Windows setup project fails to update content file

Tags: setup-project, setup-deployment

I have a .NET 4.0 solution in Visual Studio 2012 with two projects and a setup project.  Project A is a Windows Forms app.  Project B is a class library, referenced by project A.  Project B has a *.txt file, marked with a *Build Action* of *Content* and *Copy to Output* is set to *Copy Always*.

On a new installation, everything works perfectly.  However, when the installation preexists, and the deployment involves changes to the txt file, the installer fails to upgrade the preexisting txt file.  If I uninstall/reinstall the proper version of the txt file is deployed.

The process I'm going through for deployment is:

1. Incrementing the file version of each assembly for projects A & B
2. Incrementing the version of the setup project

I'm sure if I did something silly like increment the txt file name, everything would work. What am I missing to ensure the content file gets updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a known Windows Installer limitation: http://setupanddeployment.com/windows-installer-bugs/missing-files-upgrade

A solution is to modify the **Version** column in the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table for your TXT file. If you set a version, the file in your package should overwrite any existing file.